# MaterialUI two IconButtons in GridListTile

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I have the following GridListTile and want to add a second button but it is not working.

I have tried adding two ActionIcons but only one of them is displaying?

```
<GridListTile key={tile.img}>
  <img src={tile.img} alt={tile.title} />
  <GridListTileBar
    title={tile.title}
    classes={{
      root: classes.titleBar,
      title: classes.title,
    }}
    actionIcon={
      <a href={tile.link} target="_blank">
        <IconButton aria-label={`star ${tile.title}`}>
          <PlayCircleOutlineIcon
            className={classes.title}
          />
        </IconButton>
      </a>
    }
    actionIcon={
      <a href={tile.link} target="_blank">
        <IconButton aria-label={`star ${tile.title}`}>
          <PlayCircleOutlineIcon
            className={classes.title}
          />
        </IconButton>
      </a>
    }
  />
</GridListTile>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would this work?

```
      <GridListTile key={tile.img}>
        <img src={tile.img} alt={tile.title} />
        <GridListTileBar
          title={tile.title}
          classes={{
            root: classes.titleBar,
            title: classes.title,
          }}
          actionIcon={
            <>
              <a href={tile.link} target="_blank">
                <IconButton aria-label={`star ${tile.title}`}>
                  <PlayCircleOutlineIcon className={classes.title} />
                </IconButton>
              </a>
              <a href={tile.link} target="_blank">
                <IconButton aria-label={`star ${tile.title}`}>
                  <PlayCircleOutlineIcon className={classes.title} />
                </IconButton>
              </a>
            </>
          }
        />
      </GridListTile>
```